# AsyncFunction.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript

Running following code causes `apply(...) is not a function` and I'm not sure why.

I feel like invoking apply for async functions not possible. What's correct way then to get apply like calling behavior?

```js
async function throwSomething() {
  return "Apple";
}

async function caughtSomething() {
  try {
     return await throwSomething.apply(this, arguments || [])();
  } catch(e) {
     console.log(e);
  }
}

caughtSomething();
```

Comment: Because, as the error message says, `throwSomething.apply(this, arguments || [])` isn’t a function. Why do you think this `.apply` call results in a function? This has nothing to do with `async`–`await`. Try `function f(){ return ""; }` `f.apply()();`. See the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: `throwSomething.apply(this, arguments || [])();` -> `throwSomething.apply(this, arguments || []);` or perhaps you wanted to do `throwSomething.bind(this, ...arguments)();` but I'm not sure it makes much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, you just had an extra `()` after `throwSomething.apply(this, arguments || [])`

```js
async function throwSomething() {
  return "Apple";
}

async function caughtSomething() {
  try {
     return await throwSomething.apply(this, arguments || []);
  } catch(e) {
     console.log(e);
  }
}

caughtSomething().then(console.log);
```

The error says `"TypeError: throwSomething.apply(...) is not a function"`, meaning that the return value of `throwSomething.apply(...)` isn't a function. If `.apply` wasn't a function, the error would say `"TypeError: throwSomething.apply is not a function`.

Comment: Related: [TypeError: console.log(…) is not a function](/q/31013221/4642212).